# How to use surf to plot sphere function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I'm trying to plot sphere function below, But I'm getting wrong result

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I'm using

```
x1 = [-10:1:10];
x2 = [-10:1:10];
y = zeros(1,21);

for i = 1:21
    y(i) = sphere([x1(i) x2(i)]);
end
Y = meshgrid(y);
surf(x1,x2,Y);
colormap hsv;
```

`sphere.m`

```
function [y] = sphere(x)
d = length(x);
sum = 0;
for i = 1:d
    sum = sum + x(i)^2;
end
y = sum;
end
```

Comment: Did you check this example? http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#bua6ll9 there's a sphere function built into MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completness your code is not working because you are only evaluating your function on the pairs (x,x) for some x \in [-10,10] so you don't cover the whole domain. It would work with this:

```
x1 = [-10:1:10];
x2 = [-10:1:10];
y = zeros(1,21);

for i = 1:21
    for j=1:21
        Y(i,j) = sphere([x1(i) x2(j)]);
    end
end
surf(x1,x2,Y);
colormap hsv;
```

or way faster (because you should always avoid unnecessary loops for computation time reasons):

```
x1 = meshgrid([-10:1:10]);
x2 = x1';

Y = x1.^2+x2.^2;

surf(x1,x2,Y)
```

Comment: I like your meshgrid usage.

Answer (score 0):

`sphere(10)`

It is a MatLab built in function.

Please enjoy responsibly.

If you need to see the source code use: `edit sphere` or `help sphere` when your sphere function is not on the path.